# Calculate absolute time based on cycles and RTC

Tags: timers, time, rtc

I'm developing a low power data logging device. It samples sensors at the frequency of 20Hz, and also has a real time clock for absolute time (the logged time need to be exact down to ms).

I think that querying time for every samples would be wasteful of energy. One solution is calculate time based on number of cycles, and after a fixed duration (10 minutes) query RTC to update the time.

Here is my attempt:

```
#define INTERVAL 12000 //10 minutes: 10*60*20 samples

int count = 0;
int checkPointMillis;
int checkPointRTC;

// timer interrupt at 20Hz
ISR() {
    int a = analogRead(A0);
    int time = millis() - checkPointMillis + checkPointRTC;

    // write data to a buffer

    if (count > INTERVAL) {
        count = 0;
        checkPointMillis = millis();
        checkPointRTC = getRTCTime();
    }
}
```

Is this a correct approach?

Comment: The problem is that `getRTCTime` only has 1sec resolution. So at the time of the request, it could be up to 999ms off. You could use the RTC to generate an interrupt every second, and connect that to an interrupt pin. Then in the pin-change interrupt check the difference between millis and a whole seconds counter. You can use that difference to get a calibrated millis. Not sure if this is the best solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the idea is sound.  But there are problems with some of the details and tuning.

The most important detail:  Use the correct data type for storing and computing with time variables (like `time`, `checkPointMillis` and `checkPointRTC`).  The correct data type is `unsigned long` (or, equivalently, `unsigned long int` or `uint32_t`).

A second detail:  Rather than storing your calibration correction in two variables which you always use as a difference (in effect, `checkPointRTC-checkPointMillis`) just compute and store the difference.  For example:

```
...
unsigned long clockCorrection;
...
unsigned long time = millis() - clockCorrection;
...
clockCorrection = getRTCTime() - checkPointMillis;
```

This will save a few bytes of RAM and a few cycles of computation.

A third detail:  If outside of the ISR you will need to access any of the values computed in the ISR, declared their variables `volatile`.  Example:

```
volatile unsigned long time;
```

Fourth: If `getRTCTime()` or any of your sensor-reading code use interrupts, you will need to move such code out of the “timer interrupt at 20Hz” section, into (for example) `loop()`, triggered by a volatile variable going true.  [That's the model under which the balance of this answer was conceived; I overlooked, at first, the “timer interrupt at 20Hz” label.]  Note that `millis()` itself does not use interrupts.  But if your 20-Hz ISR runs longer than a millisecond, the `millis()` total will drop one millisecond per millisecond of additional ISR time.

By tuning, I refer to the number of measurement intervals to wait between recomputing the clock correction.  Under reasonable assumptions, the number of compute cycles is so closely the same with a one second interval versus a ten minute interval, that one probably should use only a second (or at the outside, a minute) interval between clock correction computes.

For example, suppose the total number of cycles awake per second is given by the following equation:

> a = 20*s + 1000*t + k * r

where *s* is the number of cycles used per sensor-set reading and recording; *t*  is the number of cycles used per clock interrupt; *k* is the number of clock correction computes per second; and *r* is the number of cycles used per clock correction compute.

For example, if *s* is 2000, *t* is 100, and *r* is 200, the equation becomes

> a = 20*2000 + 1000*100 + k * 200 = 140000 + k * 200

Now consider three cases: *k* equal to 20, or 1, or 1/600, corresponding to a clock correction compute 20 times per second, or once a second, or every 10 minutes:

```
   k           a
  20        144000
   1        144200
1/600       144000.3
```

As you can see, under the assumptions *s* is 2000, *t* is 100, and *r* is 200, there is no compelling reason to prefer 1/600 corrections per second to one  correction per second.

If your RTC can be read reliably and quickly, reading it either every time (ie 20 per second) or every second has other advantages:  you compensate more quickly for MCU clock drift (ie, every second, rather than every 10 minutes) and strongly decrease the risk of out-of-order times.

For example, if your MCU clock drifts 2 seconds fast per 10 minutes, readings taken during the first two seconds of each new 10-minute interval would show smaller times than those taken during the last two seconds of the previous interval.  With secondly corrections, no such non-monotonic readings will occur.

Here is a slightly more correct analysis of the 2 seconds fast per 10 minutes case:  2 seconds error in 600 seconds is 3.33 milliseconds per second.  With sensor readings 50 milliseconds apart, and corrected clock readings not more than 3.33 milliseconds out of whack, non-monotonicity won't occur.  However, this does not meet the “logged time needs to be exact down to ms” criterion.  To meet that, drift of more than a half millisecond must be prevented.  That requires drift correction at least 6.67 times per second.  You could accomplish that by making a  clock correction compute at every third sensor cycle.

It should be clear from the example calculations of awake cycles that the major contributor to the count is ISR cycles, here taken as 100*1000, or 100000 cycles per second.  You could set up timer 1 to interrupt 20 times per second and turn timer 0 off (which would disable `millis()` and require a different `time = ...` formula).  If each timer 1 interrupt took 1000 cycles, that would contribute 20000 cycles instead of 100000 per second.

*Edit 4:* As I noted in a comment to Edgar Bonet's answer, one can change the TOP value used for timer interrupts, to control interrupt rate with better resolution than can be obtained by merely subtracting base values.

According to Gerben's comment, “`getRTCTime` only has 1sec resolution”.  As I haven't seen any code for your `getRTCTime()` I don't know if that is true or not; but if so, here is another approach for time-rate correction:

> • At some beginning point coincident with an RTC seconds-change, record `millis()` and an RTC reading, in eg `millibase` and `RTCbase`.
>   • At some interval (eg, 10 seconds or a minute, in each case coincident with an RTC seconds-change) measure `millis()` and an RTC reading, in eg `millinow` and `RTCnow`.  Compute `RTCdeltaK` as the number of milliseconds from `RTCbase` to `RTCnow`.  Compute `millidelta` as `millinow-millibase`.
>   • Whenever elapsed time in milliseconds is needed, compute `elapsedms = ((millis()-millibase)*RTCdeltaK)/millidelta`.

The above is an algorithm, and may need some adjustment before use as an implementation.  First, the `elapsedms` calculation can be arranged to avoid division, using a scaled multiplicative factor based on `millidelta`, `RTCdeltaK`, and some powers of 2.  Secondly, relatively constant clock drift is assumed.  If that assumption is incorrect, an average ratio with exponential decay could be used, instead of just a factor equivalent to `RTCdeltaK/millidelta`.

Answer (score 2):

Yours is a classical problem of *clock synchronization*. You have a
software clock (your program's idea of the current time) which you want
to keep in sync with a reference hardware clock (the RTC). This is
typically achieved by using a [phase-locked
loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-locked_loop), or PLL. It works
as follows:

- you measure the difference between your software clock's time and the
  reference time
- you adjust your software clock based on this measurement.

This is essentially what you are already doing, except that you are
fixing your clock by stepping it abruptly, whereas a PLL would usually
slew the clock to get it in sync progressively.

Stepping the clock has some undesirable effects: it makes the time
discontinuous and, more annoyingly, it can make it non-monotonic. I
would thus recommend you try to slew your clock instead.

Here is the approach I would try if I were in your shoes. I am assuming
you are using an Arduino Uno, or a similar AVR-based board with a 16-bit
Timer 1:

- configure Timer 1 in mode 4: CTC mode with TOP = OCR1A
- set the prescaler to 64 and OCR1A = 12499 in order to get a period of
  50 ms; TIMER1_COMPA_vect will be your data gathering interrupt
- configure your RTC to generate a 1 Hz output, and route this
  signal to the input capture pin ICP1 (pin 8 on the Uno)
- run the PLL logic inside TIMER1_CAPT_vect.

Since the RTC's 1 Hz period is a multiple of the timer period, you
would expect the timer's input capture unit to always capture the same
value. The difference between two consecutive captured values is thus a
direct measure of your clock's drift in units of 4 ppm
(4 µs/s). The ISR would be basically along these lines:

```c++
ISR(TIMER1_CAPT_vect)
{
    static uint16_t last_capture;
    uint16_t this_capture = ICR1;
    int16_t drift = this_capture - last_capture;
    last_capture = this_capture;

    // Reduce the drift modulo 12500 into [-6250, +6250).
    if (drift >= 6250) drift -= 12500;
    if (drift < -6250) drift += 12500;

    tune_clock(drift);
}
```

where `tune_clock()` is your PLL algorithm responsible for slewing the
software clock.

Pay attention to the signedness of the variables. The subtraction of the
captured values should be done with unsigned numbers, *then* the result
should be made signed.

---

**Edit**: as suggested by James Waldby, I'll give here some suggestions
on the implementation of the PLL. It turns out it is not so simple:
*measuring* a clock drift is easy, *predicting* it is harder.

Let me restate the problem. You have a “good” clock: the RTC 1 Hz
signal, assumed to be perfect, but with a limited resolution of one
second. And you have a “bad” clock: Timer 1, which has a 4 µs resolution
but suffers from [frequency inaccuracy, instability and sensitivity to
temperature and supply voltage](http://jorisvr.nl/article/arduino-frequency). You want to combine
both clocks into a software clock which tracks the good clock yet has
the superior resolution of the bad clock.

I will use the following notations:

- t is the time from the reference clock (the RTC), assumed to be also
  the physical time
- n = ⌊t⌋ is the integer part of t, which is also the time when we last
  got an update from the RTC (a timer capture event)
- t′ is the time from the local clock (the Arduino timers)
- x = t′ − t is the local clock offset, measured by the ISR above at
  integer values of t; the physical time is given by t = t′ − x
- y = dx/dt is the local clock drift rate; it's a dimensionless quantity
  and typically less than 10<sup>−3</sup> (i.e. less than 1 ms/s)
- x<sub>e</sub>(t) is the estimate, made by the software, of the offset x(t)
- y<sub>e</sub>(t) = dx<sub>e</sub>/dt is the estimate of the drift rate y(t)
- t<sub>e</sub> = t′ − x<sub>e</sub>(t<sub>e</sub>) is our software
  clock: a self-consistent estimate of t

The simplest solution, which is equivalent to the one you have in your
question, is to assume x stays constant until it is updated. Thus

x<sub>e</sub>(t) = x(n)
t<sub>e</sub> = t′ − x(n)

In other words, we are just correcting for the last known offset. The
problem is, as stated before, that this gives a discontinuous time
scale.

A better solution is to try to *predict* x(n+1), and linearly
interpolate between our previous and our current prediction, thus
building a continuous piecewise linear estimate of x:

x<sub>e</sub>(t) = x<sub>e</sub>(n) + (t−n)y<sub>e</sub>(n+½),
where y<sub>e</sub>(n+½) = x<sub>e</sub>(n+1) − x<sub>e</sub>(n)

From this, the estimated time can be solved for as:

t<sub>e</sub> = n + (t′−x<sub>e</sub>(n)−n)/(1+y<sub>e</sub>(n+½))
≈ n + (t′−x<sub>e</sub>(n)−n)⋅(1−y<sub>e</sub>(n+½))

The factor 1/(1+y<sub>e</sub>(n+½)) ≈ (1−y<sub>e</sub>(n+½)) accounts
for the fact that the clock has drifted since the last update at t = n.

Now we are left with the problem of predicting x(n+1). There are
many possible approaches, and I will try to describe only a few.

### Simple PLL

One simple approach is to simulate an analog PLL with a first order
low-pass filter. Here is the first illustration of the Wikipedia article
on [phase-locked loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-locked_loop):

[image: Schematic of a PLL]

Some translation is needed between this analog picture and the digital
domain: The phase comparator takes the difference between the measured
offset x(n) and our previous prediction x<sub>e</sub>(n). The low pass
filter is implemented as an exponentially weighted moving average. The
output of the filter is our estimate of the drift rate: y<sub>e</sub>.
The VCO is the formula for estimating t<sub>e</sub>, which has the
built-in drift rate −y<sub>e</sub>. This could be translated to C++
roughly along these lines:

```c++
struct {
    uint32_t n;  // time of last update
    float xe;    // estimate of offset at time n
    float ye;    // estimate of drift rate for t in [n ,n+1]
} clock;

const float tau = 60;  // low-pass filter time constant, in seconds
const float K = 1;     // DC gain of the filter
const float alpha = 1/(1+tau);

// Called by the ISR.
// y is (x[now] - x[1 second ago]) in units of 4 us.
void tune_clock(int16_t y)
{
    static float x;   // last known offset
    x += y * 4e-6;    // update known offset
    float xe = clock.xe + clock.ye;  // estimate of current offset

    // Update time.
    clock.n++;

    // Update our estimate of the drift rate.
    clock.ye += alpha*(K*(x-xe) - clock.ye);

    // Update or estimate of the offset.
    clock.xe = xe;
}

// Estimate the current time.
float time()
{
    float t_local = micros() * 1e-6;
    return clock.n + (t_local - clock.xe - clock.n) * (1 - clock.ye);
}
```

Note that the code above is only meant as a guide. A good implementation
should use fixed-point instead of floats and should also be
rollover-safe.

The time constant of the filter should be chosen large enough to smooth
out the jitter caused by the 4 µs resolution, yet short enough to
closely track the frequency variations of the local clock. Ideally, it
should be close to the [Allan intercept](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/comp/unix/package/rtems/src/ssrlApps/ntpNanoclock/theory.htm##allan) of the x(n) time series.

This kind of PLL normally does a good job at tracking the reference
clock, but it has one drawback: it tends to carry a systematic offset.
Let's assume, for simplicity, that the drift rate is constant. Then it
can be easily seen that the steady state of the PLL carries an offset
error:

t<sub>e</sub> − t = x − x<sub>e</sub> = y/K

where K is the DC gain of the filter. A large gain minimizes this error,
but it does so at the expense of stability. Too large a DC gain and the
PLL will spontaneously go into large oscillations.

I assume it should be possible to get rid of this systematic bias by
using more sophisticated filters, maybe something like a [PID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller), but I
do not want to dive into the complexities of such filters.

### Simple linear extrapolation

Another way of estimating x(n+1), which does not suffer from systematic
bias, is to linearly extrapolate from the two last known values:

x<sub>e</sub>(n+1) = 2 x(n) − x(n−1)

This means we assume that the drift rate is constant on this
short time scale. The problem with this method is that it tends to
amplify the fluctuations due to the jitter. Assuming for example an
(overoptimistic) drift rate of 2 ppm, the measured offset will
alternate between having zero and 4 µs increments. The
extrapolation will predict every zero increment to be followed by
another zero increment, and every 4 µs increment to be followed by
another 4 µs increment, and thus it will always be wrong. The time
evolution would look as follows:

```c++
t[s]    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
x[µs]   0   0   4   4   8   8  12  12  16  16  20
xₑ[µs]  0   0   0   8   4  12   8  16  12  20  16
```

### Brown's linear exponential smoothing

[Brown's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing#Double_exponential_smoothing) is one of many linear extrapolation methods
meant to smooth-out noise in the data. It is based on running *twice*
the same low-pass filter on the input data:

```c++
s1 = low_pass(x)   // first smoothing
s2 = low_pass(s1)  // second smoothing
```

If τ is the time constant of the filter, then s<sub>1</sub> is an
average of data which has, *on average* the age τ, whereas s<sub>2</sub>
has the age 2τ. When can then, at time t, do a linear extrapolation by
running a straight line through the points (t−τ, s<sub>1</sub>) and
(t−2τ, s<sub>2</sub>). This gives the following algorithm for updating
the estimates of the offset and the drift rate:

```c++
static float s1, s2;      // x smoothed once and twice
s1 += alpha * (x - s1);   // update s1
s2 += alpha * (s1 - s2);  // update s2

// Update or estimate of the offset.
clock.xe = xe;

// Extrapolate to estimate next offset.
xe = s1 + (s1-s2)*(tau+1)/tau;

// Update our estimate of the drift rate.
clock.ye = xe - clock.xe;
```

Here again, the optimal time constant should be of the order of the
Allan intercept. Note that the limit τ → 0 gives the simple
extrapolation of the previous section.

The figure below shows the performance of this algorithm on simulated
data. The simulated clock has a drift rate oscillating between 1.7 and
2.3 ppm, and its measured offset is rounded to the closest multiple of
4 µs. The line labeled “predicted (τ = 0)” is the simple
extrapolation of the previous section:

[image: Clock offset extrapolation]

Here, the large jitter of the simple extrapolation method is quite
obvious. On this simulated data, Brown's method works well with a time
constant on the order of 5 s. The frequency of a real clock would
change much more slowly, and a longer time constant would work better.

Now, all this is probably too general for your particular use case. I
didn't know when I started this edit it would lead me so far... If you
can tolerate more than, say, 10 µs of jitter, then the simple
extrapolation should be good enough. And if you only need the time at
t′-periodic intervals, this may enable some optimizations.

Comment: The approach of adjusting the drift count due to 6250+ deviation can keep time at perhaps one part per thousand.  However, adjusting the TOP value would allow correction in increments of about one part per 12500.   In other words,  the value loaded into OCR1A should slowly change, over a period of minutes or hours, to produce correct interrupt rate.

Comment: @JamesWaldby-jwpat7: I don't understand your comment “_[...] can keep time at perhaps one part per thousand_”. A properly implemented PLL has exactly zero long term drift (it keeps time at zero parts per million), with only short term variations (phase noise) which depend on the clocks and the PLL time constant. One part in 12500 is 80 ppm, very crude compared with the 4 ppm resolution you get using input capture.

Comment: EB, I misunderstood part of your answer and withdraw most of my comment.   It isn't clear to me what control the PLL will vary, what its resolution is, etc.  Perhaps in your answer you could show a typical PLL-corrected `time = ...` calculation.

Comment: @JamesWaldby-jwpat7: Added some options for the PLL algorithm. That was a looong digression...

Comment: EB, yes.  Great exposition; I'd upvote your answer again if I could.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a RTC a far better solution to use alarms.

I use `TimeAlarms` for this purpose

```
#include <Time.h>        //http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Code/Time
#include <Timezone.h>    //https://github.com/JChristensen/Timezone
#include <TimeAlarms.h> //  Time alarms for use with Time library
#include <DS1307RTC.h>   //http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Code/Time returns time as a time_t
```

then include code to do something. The following waits for the Minutes to rollover, then calls function `Repeats` every 30 seconds etc

```
const int SampleRate = 30;  // seconds >1

  Alarm.waitMinuteRollover();
  Alarm.timerRepeat(SampleRate, Repeats);           // timer for every SampleRate seconds
  Alarm.alarmRepeat(alarmTime, rolloverLogFile);    // alarm to rollover LogFile (daily)
```

Comment: [TimeAlarms](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_TimeAlarms.html) can run stuff at one-second-accuracy times, but not 20 times per second.  But perhaps you are referring to using an alarm just for the every-ten-minutes stuff?